# '?))' at line 2, query was: SELECT `e`.`entity_id` FROM `catalog_product_super_link` AS `l`

Tags: magento2

Trying a new shipment module and just upgraded to the latest version of magento open source. When I want to use this module I get an error and see this in my debug log. I have searched but this error is so generic, not sure where to start with troubleshooting this, anybody have a point where I can start? I already disabled all my third party modules etc but no luck.

```
[2023-09-05T11:24:59.508073+00:00] main.ERROR: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?))' at line 2, query was: SELECT `e`.`entity_id` FROM `catalog_product_super_link` AS `l`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` ON e.entity_id = l.parent_id WHERE (l.product_id IN(?))
```